# How to read properties file in /WEB-INF/conf folder in a JAX-WS service

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-ws, properties-file

I tried reading the properties file like this, but it keeps failing.

```
public class ReadPropertiesWS {
    private static final String filename = "WEBINF/conf/sample.properties";
    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext context;
    private static Properties properties = new Properties();

    public ReadPropertiesWS() throws IOException {
        ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) context
                .getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);
        InputStream in = servletContext
                .getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/conf/sample.properties");
        try {
            properties.load(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I'm using JAX-WS and it's deployed in Tomcat.

Comment: There's nothing anywhere that suggests that a `WebServiceContext` can be cast to a `ServletContext`. Is there any particular reason you want to store a properties file in the WEB-INF directory of your application?

Comment: I want some configurable values

Comment: Keeps failing, how?